# Problem with caption when using longtable

Tags: longtable

When I try to add \footnotesize, the caption of the table will a little overlap with the table. Can someone help me? Thanks

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man,natbib]{apa6}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}

\title{AAA}
\shorttitle{AAA}

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{longtable}{|p{.25\textwidth}|p{.20\textwidth}|p{.50\textwidth}|}
\hline
Why Startups Fail & David Feinleib & If you read only one book make it this one!  Presents the key failure modes for startups and what you can do to avoid them. \\ \hline
\caption{\label{tab:widgets}Startup books.}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In `longtable` the caption normaly is inside table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `longable` it is assumed that the caption is on top of table (if the table span more pages, this is very expected features, isn't it? And `caption`: is part of table:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man,natbib]{apa6}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}

\title{AAA}
\shorttitle{AAA}

\begin{document}
    \centering
\begin{longtable}{|p{.25\textwidth}|p{.20\textwidth}|p{.50\textwidth}|}
    \caption{Startup books.}
    \label{tab:widgets}
    \\  \hline
Why Startups Fail   
    &   David Feinleib    
        &   If you read only one book make it this one!  
            Presents the key failure modes for startups and what you can do to avoid them. 
    \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
    \end{document}
```

which gives:
[image]

Comment: I checked APA 6th, you are right, the caption of table should be at top of the table. Thank you so much!

Comment: It works perfect even I change the font size.

Comment: @HongboMiao, I'm glad that my answer help you! Happy TeXing!